# Button inside SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, simplecursoradapter

I've a ListView that I populate with a SimpleCursorAdapter. For each item in my list i've, in this order: TextView > RatingBar > TextView > ImageView. I want to add a button on the ImageView but I dont know how to this...

Where I populate the ListView:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.beerdrunk, cursor,
            new String[] { "beers", "notes", "numbers" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.champName, R.id.champNote, R.id.champDrunk });
    adapter.setViewBinder(binder);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMyBeers);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onClickBeer);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The OnItemClickListener:

```
private OnItemClickListener onClickBeer = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        System.out.println(""+ arg0);
        System.out.println(""+ arg1);
        System.out.println(""+arg2);
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(MyBeers.this, DetailsBeer.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("com.example.checkmybeer.DetailsBeer", ""
                + arg3);
        startActivityForResult(newActivity, 0);
    }
};
```

And the XML for beerdrunk:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/champName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="130"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/beerBook"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="1.5dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/champNote"
    style="@style/beerRatingSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:isIndicator="true"        
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_margin="1.5dp"
    android:rating="5"
    android:stepSize="0.10" >
</RatingBar>

<View
    android:layout_width="1.5dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/champDrunk"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="200"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1.5dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/champPlusone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/plus2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried something like:

```
    if(arg2 instanceof ImageView){
     //do some stuff
    }
```

But it does not work... How can i do to know which view is clicked inside my "row" ?

Comment: "How can i do to know which view is clicked inside my "row" ?" You need to create a custom adapter and set OnClickListeners in each View that you want to have a special action.

Comment: Quick question, why do you want to add a button to your listview? As opposed to just have users click on the row itself?

Comment: @BrentHronik I assume the author wants the RatingsBar to do one thing, the Button to do another, and possibly the row itself to do something different.

Comment: Ok thanks Sam for your answer :)
@BrentHronik, click on the row do something different than click on the button inside the same row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to click on an image, use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) instead of an ImageView.
You can then set the `onClick` attribute on the button that calls a method in your Activity.

Extend a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and in the `bindView` method add `onClick` listeners for each button. (Maybe make it call a method in your activity ... `public void buttonClicked(int position, View v)...` so you know which row and which view was clicked.

Here is an example implementation of [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) you could use.

```
class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
        super(context,c,flags);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        int row_id = cursor.get('_id');  //Your row id (might need to replace)
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.champPlusone);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //ADD STUFF HERE you know which row is clicked. and which button
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beerdrunk, parent, false);
        bindView(v,context,cursor);
        return v;
    }

}
```

;)

Comment: This and Sam's comment help me a lot !! :)