# Can't add Onclick action with button in listview row

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm fresh n funky in android dev. I start learning and got stoped by clickable button in listview!

```
  `public class Test2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Test2";
    Button btnEdytuj;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;`

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    displayList();
}

private void displayList() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllData();
    String from[] = new String[]{myDb.COL_ID, myDb.COL_NAZWA, myDb.COL_LAT, myDb.COL_LON};
    int to[] = new int[]{R.id.textView10, R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3};
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item_edit, cursor, from, to, 0);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            btnEdytuj = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonEE);
            btnEdytuj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    // Do something
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Test2.this,Edytuj.class);
                    startActivity(intent);`
```

And my wish is to open new activity from list by intent trigger by pressing a row or a button and passing an id to handle editing.

**I have found an error maybe it will helps to figure it out:**

`android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView`

Comment: The accepted answer there uses ImageButton, but of course you can use normal Button

Comment: first check your button is at most of screen, no other hidden view is there

Answer (score 1):

in your list adapter do this :

this for get view function :

```
  @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note, null);

          btnEdytuj = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEE);
          btnEdytuj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){ 
             // Do something
               }
           });

      }

            return convertView;
        }
```

this other for bind view:

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        int row_id = cursor.get('_id');  //Your row id (might need to replace)
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonEE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //ADD STUFF HERE you know which row is clicked. and which button
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's a Cursor adapter, so it's bindView, not getView

Comment: use this: android:onClick="myClickHandler" public void myClickHandler(View v) {}

Comment: use this post http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: Again, it's not a regular adapter, please [edit] accordingly

Comment: plz check this its will help you: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: Why are you duplicating comments? That link doesn't answer the question

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: try if it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Write your code here
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about the button in the view, not clicking the view itself

Comment: Then simply in the adapter we can access the view and setOnClickListener on it.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the button `onClick` method inside `Adapter` class.

As you have used `SimpleCursorAdapter`, use [button-inside-simplecursoradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146846/button-inside-simplecursoradapter) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly write following code in your activity class.

**MainActivity.java**

```
ArrayList<MobileData> searchResults = getMobileData();
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv1.setAdapter(new MobileAdapter(this, searchResults));
```

Add all list item by using adapter class and also add button event in adaptaer class.

**MobileAdapter.java**

```
public class MobileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<MobileData> searchArrayList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
MobilezonDAO dao;

public MobileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MobileData> results) {
    this.context = context;
    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    dao = new MobilezonDAO(this.context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.mobileImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobileImage);
        holder.mobileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobileName);
        holder.mobilePrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobilePrice);
        holder.mobileBrand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobileBrand);
        holder.viewDetails = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);
        holder.addToCart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.mobileImage.setImageBitmap(searchArrayList.get(position).getMobileImage());
    holder.mobileName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getMobileName());
    holder.mobilePrice.setText("Price: $"+searchArrayList.get(position).getMobilePrice());
    holder.mobileBrand.setText("Brand: "+searchArrayList.get(position).getMobileBrand());
    holder.viewDetails.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_details);
    holder.viewDetails.setId(position);
    holder.addToCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addtocart);

    holder.viewDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MobileData mobileData = searchArrayList.get(holder.viewDetails.getId());

            Intent intent= new Intent(context, MobileViewDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ModelNumber", mobileData.getModelNumber());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MobileData mobileData = searchArrayList.get(holder.viewDetails.getId());

            CartData cartData = new CartData();
            cartData.setUsername(emailid);
            cartData.setModelNumber(mobileData.getModelNumber());
            cartData.setPrice(mobileData.getMobilePrice());
            cartData.setQuantity("1");

            CartData tempCartData = dao.searchParticularCartData(cartData.getUsername(), cartData.getModelNumber());

            if(tempCartData!=null && tempCartData.getQuantity()!=null && Integer.valueOf(tempCartData.getQuantity())>0){
                Snackbar.make(view, "Selected Mobile already added in your cart.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }else{
                dao.insertCartData(cartData);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Mobile has been successfully added in your cart.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mobileImage;
    TextView mobileName;
    TextView mobilePrice;
    TextView mobileBrand;
    Button viewDetails;
    Button addToCart;
}
```

}

Comment: The question is about the button in the view, not clicking the view itself

Comment: You can set the onClick event in your custom adapter's getView method..
check the link http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: You copied the exact same link as the other answer. Once again, it does not help. I've closed this post as a duplicate, please refer to it

Comment: The question used a CursorAdapter.... Also, a minimal example would have been better than an object with 6 fields.